# xCode Objective C: Custom UITableViewCell Connections

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to implement a custom UITableView cell as the prototype for a tableview. So I make a custom class called CustomCell and set the class in the protoype cell from UITableViewCell to CustomCell, but I'm not sure how to connect my UI elements inside the prototype cell to their corresponding Outlets inside CustomCell (because custom cell isn't a view controller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter that custom cell isn't a view controller, you can ctrl-drag and drop your outlets in exactly the same way from the view elements in Interface Builder to your CustomCell.h file.

Comment: Oh. Well, that was embarrassing :) Thanks!

Comment: I still can't figure out how to do that with storyboards.. because there is no files owner. I guess thats another question altogether.

Comment: Afraid I have no experience with storyboards so I can't help you there.

Comment: Same problem with storyboards - seems to be a bug where the workaround is to create the outlets manually in code and THEN connect them in IB

Answer (score 0):

Try for example this tutorial: http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder